# Median values over time

Tags: median, large-data

I'm evaluating a large data set in pandas (over 4 million rows), and finding that the median values for a couple of my datapoints are completely unchanged over a period of three months.

For example, when looking at a set of miles per day and calculating medians per month I get this:

Median miles per day:
**January**: 0.916667
**February**: 0.916667
**March**: 0.916667

The population does behave consistently month over month, but does it make sense that the medians are completely the same? Is there something about calculating medians for large populations that may case this result? When I take random samples of the population the trend does persist.

Here's an example of how the raw data looks:

| Date | Miles |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-23 | 1.56000 |
| 2022-03-17 | 0.66667 |
| 2022-01-15 | 1.125000 |
| 2022-02-01 | 0.58333 |
| 2022-02-11 | .625000 |
| 2022-01-04 | .791667 |

Comment: I think I would suspect a bug. I certainly wouldn't expect such medians to be the same, *if you are computing the medians over disjoint data sets*. If you have overlap, inadvertent or otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: I get new numbers every month, so there is not supposed to be any overlap. I also checked and the IDs are indeed unique.
I've gone through my code looking for any bugs, and everything's looking fine. It's very odd.

Comment: If I were you, I would use a completely independent computation method as a sanity check. Do it by hand, or import the data into Excel, or something other than how you're computing the medians right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data appears to be in fractions of miles (2/3, 1/8, etc.). Can’t tell if it is due to customary behavior in your region, or maybe simply a resolution problem in your measurement system.

You can easily see it if you sort the values from low to high, and make a line plot. You will see that it looks more like a staircase than like a smooth curve.

That means that it is not really continuous data, but it rather behaves more like ordinal data. You probably expect the medians near each other; the resolution issue doesn’t allow the median to vary at all.

Comment: I am calculating distances traveled, and they are indeed mostly fractions and not whole numbers. I understand that a median may work with such kinds of data, so should I just take the results as they are?
I've also tried to compute in Tableau and Excel and receive the same result.

Comment: The median does reflect the information contained in your data. 

The thing for you to decide, is if the information in your data corresponds to the information about the physical real world that you are studying. How relevant is it to be able to detect small differences of which size, and is your measurement system capable of doing that? And, are you really interested in the average—> median, or is the interest actually in the tails of the distribution —> e.g. 5th percentile?